# PHP cURL request - Cloudflare

Tags: php, cloudflare

is there any way to bypass Cloudflare with PHP cURL request?

Like solving the captcha manually and then passing the data to the cURL request?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

It's needed to save the cookies and control the session manually, so you can display the captcha for the user to solve through some page and then you will be able to resume the cURL process.

However it's a lot of work as you will have to sniff and understand how Cloudflare works in order to make the right requests. Therefore... haven't you considered using PhantomJS, CasperJS, SlimerJS or NightmareJS?